# Como unir 2 consultas sql en 1 sola utilizando sum y where

Tags: sql

Tengo que representar las sumatorias anuales por tipo de factura y tipo de contratos, las 2 consultas que tengo por separado es igual a esto:

```
  SELECT ejercicio , SUM(importe) AS FACTURA FROM DASH_CLIENTES WHERE tipo = 'F' Group by ejercicio 

  SELECT ejercicio, SUM(importe) AS CONTRATADO FROM DASH_CLIENTES WHERE tipo = 'C' Group by ejercicio
```

el detalle es que deseo la estructura  asi:

```
Ejercicio | FACTURA | CONTRATO
----------|---------|----------
2022      | 12123   | 2233333
..........|.........|..........
```

Y no por separado como están las consultas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso se logra fácilmente usando `CASE` dentro de las funciones de agregado.

```
SELECT ejercicio, 
       SUM( CASE WHEN tipo = 'F' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) AS Factura,
       SUM( CASE WHEN tipo = 'C' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) AS Contratado
FROM DASH_CLIENTES 
WHERE tipo IN ( 'F' , 'C')
GROUP BY ejercicio;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias si funciono